# Laravel - Algolia: multiple where in search

Tags: laravel, eloquent, algolia

I'm looking to add one more search condition to the following functionality:

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
        ->where('tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0])
        ->get();
```

I would like to add one more condition, similar to:

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
        ->where('tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0])
        **->where('categoria', '=', $categoria_id)**
        ->get();
```

it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
// This, as u mentioned, gonna work.
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
    ->where('tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0])
    ->where('categoria', '=', $categoria_id)
    ->get();

 // This can also Work
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
    ->where([
        ['tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0]]
        ['categoria', '=', $categoria_id]
    ])
    ->get();
```

There are other ways base on what you wanna do, but above are the easiest approach which they're work.

Good Luck.